# Minecraft hangs itself when launching

Tags: java, minecraft

When I start minecraft, I get the following:

```
marc@marc-desktop:~$ java -jar '/home/marc/Schreibtisch/Minecraft.jar' 
Bootstrap (v5)
Current time is Feb 19, 2016 8:42:21 PM
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Linux'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '4.2.0-27-generic'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'amd64'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.8.0_66-internal'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '64'

Looking for update
Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma
Got reply in: 612ms
No update found.
Reversing LZMA on /home/marc/.minecraft/launcher.pack.lzma to /home/marc/.minecraft/launcher.pack
Unpacking /home/marc/.minecraft/launcher.pack to /home/marc/.minecraft/launcher.jar
Cleaning up /home/marc/.minecraft/launcher.pack
Starting launcher.
```

This is normal and meant to happen. The problem is that it hangs and I loose all ability to interact with the window. I recently switched to Ubuntu from Fedora and when I was using fedora 23 everything was working well. Therefore,  it must be an Ubuntu issue problem. I am using `openjdk-8-jre`.

Comment: Switch to sun java and try again.

Comment: thank you for this advice but i dont really know how to do this.

Comment: Install proper package (for example sun-java6-bin) and if `/etc/alternatives/java` does not point to something like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java` issue command `update-alternatives --config java` and it will let you choose your java machine.